# Activator.CreateInstance with Delegate parameter

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, delegates

I want to create an instance of an internal class from a third party assembly with reflection.

The class looks like this

```
    internal sealed class SomeClass
    {
        public delegate object SomeDelegate(object value);

        public SomeDelegateHandler { get; private set; }

        public SomeClass(SomeDelegate handler)
        {
            this.Handler = handler;
        }
    }
```

Usually I would use reflection to create instances of an internal class but I need to pass a `SomeDelegate` delegate.

Since that delegate is inside the internal class I need to create an instance of that delegate via reflection, too. But everything I already tried, did not work

This is what I tried so far.

```
// This is the method that I need to pass as an argument
public static object SomeDelegateImplementation(object value)
{
    return value;
}

public void Main()
{
    // example: create SomeClass without reflection 
    // (this is how SomeClass is usually constructed);
    var instance = new SomeClass(SomeDelegateImplementation);

    // setup: get the ConstructorInfo so I can use 
    // ctor.Invoke(...) to create an instance of that class
    var assembly = typeof(ThirdParty.OtherClass).Assembly;
    var type = assembly.GetType("ThirdParty.SomeClass", true, true);
    var ctor = type.GetConstructors()[0];

    // method one (doesn't work)
    // compiler error: cannot convert method group 'SomeDelegateImplementation' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?
    var args = new object[]{ SomeDelegateImplementation }; 
    var instance = ctor.Invoke(args);

    // method two (doen't work)
    // throws a runtime error during invoke: 
    // error converting object with type "System.Func`2[System.Object,System.Object]" to type "ThirdParty.SomeClass+SomeDelegate".
    Func<object, object> someDelegateImplementation = SomeDelegateImplementation;
    var args = new object[]{ (Delegate)someDelegateImplementation }; 
    var instance = ctor.Invoke(args);
}
```

Comment: Do you know the type of delegate that you want to create at compile-time, or is that dynamic as well? It's not clear what your real context would be. But Delegate.CreateDelegate is probably what you want, if it's all dynamic.

Comment: I agree with Jon. A delegate always refers to a method (including anonymous methods and lambdas). So in order to create a delegate you need to connect the referenced method with the new delegate variable you want to create.
In reflection `MethodInfo.CreateDelegate` or `Delegate.CreateDelegate` is the way to go.

Comment: @JonSkeet I know the type but it's inside the internal class in a third party assembly so I need relection for that as well. `var t = assembly.GetType("ThirdParty.SomeClass+SomeDelegateHandler ", true, true); var method = this.GetType().GetMethod("SomeDelegateImplementation"); var args = new [] { Delegate.CreateDelegate(t, m); }` works. Thanks Jon, didn't know about `CreateDelegate`. If you post this as an answer I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: I'll do that if you edit the question to clarify it, ideally with a complete example. That will make it a more useful question for future visitors.

Comment: @JonSkeet I updated my question to include more details and a solution.

Comment: If you've got a solution, please move that to an answer - it shouldn't be part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Thanks to @JonSkeet I manged to create an instance of `SomeClass` with using `Delegate.CreateDelegate`

```
    Assembly assembly = typeof(ThirdParty.OtherClass).Assembly;
    Type type = assembly.GetType("ThirdParty.SomeClass", true, true);
    ConstructorInfo ctor = type.GetConstructors()[0];

    // get a reference to the original delegate type
    Type someDelegateHandler Type =
        assembly.GetType("ThirdParty.SomeClass+SomeDelegateHandler", true, true);

    // get a reference to my method
    MethodInfo someDelegateImplementationMethod = 
        typeof(Program).GetMethod("SomeDelegateImplementation", 
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    // create a delegate that points to my method
    Delegate someDelegateImplementationDelegate = 
        Delegate.CreateDelegate(
            someDelegateHandler, someDelegateImplementationMethod);

    object[] args = new object[]{ someDelegateImplementationDelegate  };
    object instance = ctor.Invoke(args);
```